# Can hurricane shutters be installed horizontally? 

Tags: installation, hurricane-panels

Looking at the [photos](http://www.stormshutters.com/storm-panels/installation_photos.html) at this site, it appears that they are able to be installed horizontally.

Do you have to use a track or can you drill into the shutters and then Tapcon them to the masonry? I am thinking of using 2 inch L x 1/4 wide Tapcon for this application.

For my application, there is a sill that protrudes out underneath my windows, which prevents me from placing the shutters vertical in a track. The protrusion looks something like this (see brick under window):

[image: Windows with hurricane shutters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. I have to measure the width of my sill, but I think I will need a H and F track with build-out. A description of tracks was [located here](http://www.hurricaneshutters2go.com/pdfs/Descriptions%20of%20Track.pdf).